# Yii swift mail attachment

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am able to send mails with attachments using yiimailmessage extension which uses swiftmailer  but no attachment is found in mail. It says "no preview is available". Where am I going wrong here?

```
$uploadedfile=CUploadedfile::getInstance($model,'others');

$uploadedFileName=$uploadedfile->tempName;

$swiftAttachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($uploadedFileName); 

$message->attach($swiftAttachment);
```

Comment: You should post your code so that we can help you.

Comment: $uploadedfile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($$model,'others');




$uploadedFileName=$uploadedfile->tempName;
  $swiftAttachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($uploadedFileName); 
        $message->attach($swiftAttachment);

Comment: Better if you edit the question and post all the details in there.

Comment: can u provide solution now

Comment: $uploadfile != $uploadedfile

Comment: i changed that still in attachment in email shows no preview

Comment: You are attaching fromPath the $uploadedFileName, but are you sure that the path is correct? Debug that, and see if the path to the file shows you the actual image.

Comment: ya the path is right i am  retrieving from a temporary location where here $uploadedFileName provides temporary path name of the file uploaded

Comment: frompath is tmp/somerandomfilename.tmp